# Azure Management API - Failed to retrieve Data Masking settings

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-api-management

I am calling the below Azure management API and got the "Failed to retrieve Data Masking settings" exception. I don't know why it is occurring.

GET [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/{serverName}/databases/{databaseName}/dataMaskingPolicies/Default?api-version=2014-04-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/%7BserverName%7D/databases/%7BdatabaseName%7D/dataMaskingPolicies/Default?api-version=2014-04-01)

Can anyone tell, what is the reason for this exception?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: please remove azure-api-management - which is a separate product/service - as this might be misleading and does not relate to this question

Comment: I am using Azure management API that's why I have added it.

Answer (score 0):

The data you trying to get using mentioned Azure Management API might be sensitive and therefore need masking of the column in which you are inserting it.

> Dynamic data masking helps prevent unauthorized access to sensitive data by enabling customers to designate how much of the sensitive data to reveal with minimal impact on the application layer. It’s a policy-based security feature that hides the sensitive data in the result set of a query over designated database fields, while the data in the database is not changed.

You can apply Dynamic Data Masking in the Azure SQL database using the Azure portal. Please refer the example given below.

Log in to the Azure portal and click on SQL Databases.

Click on the database where you are going to set up **Dynamic Data Masking.**

[image]

Under the **Security** section, click on **Dynamic Data Masking**. This page shows the list of tables and columns in the database that is recommended for masking.

[image]

Click on **Add mask** button to mask the column using the default Dynamic Data Masking function. Click on **Save** to apply the masking.

[image]

Now if you run SELECT query to retrieve the data from the database, you still be able to see the unmasked data as you have the appropriate permissions to view data.

Execute the following script to add new user and assign `db_datareader` rule.

```
CREATE USER myuser WITH PASSWORD = '<pwd>'

ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [myuser]
```

Now if you login using the credentials of this new user, and run any SELECT query, you can observe that the column which you have masked showing XXXX. It implies that masking has been applied to this column and an unauthorized user won’t be able to see the data.

[image]

I suggest you to please go through [Dynamic data masking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/dynamic-data-masking-overview) for more information.

Comment: Thanks you @UtkarshPal-MT for your response. When we call the same API, we are able to get response for most of the databases but for few databases we are getting this "Failed to retrieve Data Masking settings" error

Comment: You might need to check the Data masking settings for those databases for which you are facing issue? does the user has administrative privileges?

Comment: The user has reader permission on all the subscriptions. We have also checked other subscriptions for which the user has reader permission and the above API is returning the result.

Comment: In this scenario, the issue could be with any small configuration. The approach you can practice is compare configuration and user permissions for the database API is working and other database it's not working. are also schemas same? It might be issue with schema structure. Also, are you are getting any error code, plz share.

Comment: we are getting 500 (Internal Server Error) code.